# Interactive graph changes from many colors to black only when clicked on

Tags: r, r-highcharter, d3tree

I create an interactive treemap based on the following code:

```
library(treemap)
library(devtools)
install_github("timelyportfolio/d3treeR")
library(d3treeR)
    
tm2 <- treemap(
    
    dtf = mData_col,
    
    index = c("GICS_SECTOR_NAME", "Virk"),
    
    vSize = "CUR_MKT_CAP_EUR",
    
    vColor = "myColors",
    
    type = "color"
    
    )
    
    d3tree3(tm2 ,rootname = "S&P500")
```

The column "myColors" are created as follows: Each return gets an unique color going from red (negative returns) to green (positive returns):

```
myColors = paletteer_c("ggthemes::Classic Red-Green", length(bloomData$CURRENT_TRR_3MO))
```

Which yields:
[image]

So all the colours are perfect here. But when I zoom in it just turns black and white? Do you folks have any idea why?

[image]

[image]

Code that can replicate the data.frame that is used:

```
mData_col = structure(structure(
  list(
    SHORT_NAME = c(
      "VALEO",
      "AZEK CO INC/THE",
      "META PLATFORMS-A",
      "ALIGN TECHNOLOGY",
      "APTIV PLC",
      "PUMA SE",
      "INFINEON TECH",
      "GENERAL MOTORS C",
      "ING GROEP NV",
      "INTUITIVE SURGIC",
      "NIKE INC -CL B",
      "DSM (KONIN)",
      "MARVELL TECHNOLO",
      "SAP SE",
      "TJX COS INC",
      "DUFRY AG-REG",
      "SALESFORCE.COM",
      "QUALCOMM INC",
      "VOLVO AB-B",
      "LVMH MOET HENNE",
      "DSV A/S",
      "CHIPOTLE MEXICAN",
      "NVIDIA CORP",
      "VONOVIA SE",
      "PFIZER INC",
      "MICROSOFT CORP",
      "WALT DISNEY CO/T",
      "JPMORGAN CHASE",
      "GENMAB A/S",
      "BOOKING HOLDINGS",
      "NEXTERA ENERGY",
      "GENERAC HOLDINGS",
      "PRYSMIAN SPA",
      "PARKER HANNIFIN",
      "CTS EVENTIM AG &",
      "NESTLE SA-REG",
      "NN GROUP",
      "ENGIE",
      "FISERV INC",
      "ALPHABET INC-C",
      "MONDELEZ INTER-A",
      "PROCTER & GAMBLE",
      "ASSA ABLOY AB-B",
      "SEGRO PLC",
      "APPLE INC",
      "AMAZON.COM INC",
      "PEPSICO INC",
      "VESTAS WIND SYST",
      "ANHEUSER-BUSCH I",
      "ROCHE HLDG-GENUS",
      "VISA INC-CLASS A",
      "UNITEDHEALTH GRP",
      "DEUTSCHE TELEKOM",
      "ALLIANZ SE-REG",
      "ACCOR SA",
      "NOVO NORDISK-B",
      "ELI LILLY & CO",
      "ARCELORMITTAL",
      "RWE AG",
      "PALO ALTO NETWOR",
      "SPIRIT AEROSYS-A",
      "CATERPILLAR INC",
      "UNION PAC CORP",
      "LONDON STOCK EX",
      "QUANTA SERVICES",
      "ADP",
      "MTU AERO ENGINES",
      "FREEPORT-MCMORAN",
      "EQUINOR ASA",
      "ANGLO AMER PLC",
      "CHEVRON CORP"
    ),
    CUR_MKT_CAP_EUR = c(
      3780527961.885,
      4559874262.35656,
      646674588530.244,
      39490654609.3844,
      35145247442.3341,
      11797503340.8,
      40052601271.79,
      71001155309.7512,
      37529779767.352,
      112826727606.333,
      230784501073.123,
      28114332764.65,
      66361806122.4,
      123784086416.32,
      79964791616.5763,
      3548992091.81653,
      236896195140,
      194785187002,
      3900484756109.26,
      323700881500.7,
      319200000000,
      47903113191.0745,
      730064081840,
      34131455246.55,
      328495256039.221,
      2499696636206.72,
      279730539055.265,
      461810736139.515,
      155987116593,
      98730280238.9059,
      178321879754.243,
      22655934082.8066,
      8237391237.12,
      40888681785.0338,
      5761920000,
      347755465944,
      14120150088.2,
      29466948633.0999,
      71877512165.3115,
      2030620676808.37,
      93736663619.9131,
      399235147815.955,
      3098454597353.48,
      13113870238.8599,
      3021185669281.29,
      1840157216728.19,
      249319031613.142,
      195106354632,
      107928483456.85,
      308256524005.963,
      518559780489.195,
      521384124570.439,
      82914833534.288,
      87062795629.95,
      7606924585.4,
      1726956000000,
      297658886513.073,
      27885773600.155,
      25094525981.28,
      64520156416.0414,
      5510386491.55821,
      130876608687.381,
      185682844126.015,
      36530154218.6868,
      20171088907.0297,
      13023215223.2,
      11515468344,
      79542301438.9622,
      1039528147303.7,
      39471875850.0022,
      350444879702.601
    ),
    GICS_SECTOR_NAME = c(
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Industrials",
      "Communication Services",
      "Health Care",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Information Technology",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Financials",
      "Health Care",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Materials",
      "Information Technology",
      "Information Technology",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Information Technology",
      "Information Technology",
      "Industrials",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Industrials",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Information Technology",
      "Real Estate",
      "Health Care",
      "Information Technology",
      "Communication Services",
      "Financials",
      "Health Care",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Utilities",
      "Industrials",
      "Industrials",
      "Industrials",
      "Communication Services",
      "Consumer Staples",
      "Financials",
      "Utilities",
      "Information Technology",
      "Communication Services",
      "Consumer Staples",
      "Consumer Staples",
      "Industrials",
      "Real Estate",
      "Information Technology",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Consumer Staples",
      "Industrials",
      "Consumer Staples",
      "Health Care",
      "Information Technology",
      "Health Care",
      "Communication Services",
      "Financials",
      "Consumer Discretionary",
      "Health Care",
      "Health Care",
      "Materials",
      "Utilities",
      "Information Technology",
      "Industrials",
      "Industrials",
      "Industrials",
      "Financials",
      "Industrials",
      "Industrials",
      "Industrials",
      "Materials",
      "Energy",
      "Materials",
      "Energy"
    ),
    CURRENT_TRR_3MO = c(
      -41.4,
      -39.8,
      -35.4,
      -30.1,
      -27.2,
      -26.7,-24.8,
      -21.7,
      -21.6,
      -21.3,
      -19.5,
      -18.6,
      -18.5,
      -18.4,
      -16.8,-13.8,
      -13.8,
      -13.4,
      -13.2,
      -12.5,
      -11.6,
      -10.9,
      -10.5,
      -10.1,-9,
      -9,
      -8.8,
      -8.8,
      -8.5,
      -8.3,
      -8.2,
      -7.8,
      -7.2,
      -6.6,
      -6.3,-6.3,
      -6.1,
      -6.1,
      -4.8,
      -4.7,
      -4.7,
      -4.6,
      -4.6,
      -4.4,
      -4.1,-3.6,
      -2.6,
      -1.3,
      -0.4,
      0.3,
      1,
      2.3,
      2.6,
      3,
      3.2,
      3.4,
      4.8,
      4.8,
      5.8,
      6.3,
      8.2,
      8.5,
      8.7,
      12.3,
      15.3,
      17,
      18.2,
      21.6,
      31.9,
      33.2,
      42.4
    ),
    Virk = c(
      "VALEO (-41.4%)",
      "AZEK CO INC/THE (-39.8%)",
      "META PLATFORMS-A (-35.4%)",
      "ALIGN TECHNOLOGY (-30.1%)",
      "APTIV PLC (-27.2%)",
      "PUMA SE (-26.7%)",
      "INFINEON TECH (-24.8%)",
      "GENERAL MOTORS C (-21.7%)",
      "ING GROEP NV (-21.6%)",
      "INTUITIVE SURGIC (-21.3%)",
      "NIKE INC -CL B (-19.5%)",
      "DSM (KONIN) (-18.6%)",
      "MARVELL TECHNOLO (-18.5%)",
      "SAP SE (-18.4%)",
      "TJX COS INC (-16.8%)",
      "DUFRY AG-REG (-13.8%)",
      "SALESFORCE.COM (-13.8%)",
      "QUALCOMM INC (-13.4%)",
      "VOLVO AB-B (-13.2%)",
      "LVMH MOET HENNE (-12.5%)",
      "DSV A/S (-11.6%)",
      "CHIPOTLE MEXICAN (-10.9%)",
      "NVIDIA CORP (-10.5%)",
      "VONOVIA SE (-10.1%)",
      "PFIZER INC (-9%)",
      "MICROSOFT CORP (-9%)",
      "WALT DISNEY CO/T (-8.8%)",
      "JPMORGAN CHASE (-8.8%)",
      "GENMAB A/S (-8.5%)",
      "BOOKING HOLDINGS (-8.3%)",
      "NEXTERA ENERGY (-8.2%)",
      "GENERAC HOLDINGS (-7.8%)",
      "PRYSMIAN SPA (-7.2%)",
      "PARKER HANNIFIN (-6.6%)",
      "CTS EVENTIM AG & (-6.3%)",
      "NESTLE SA-REG (-6.3%)",
      "NN GROUP (-6.1%)",
      "ENGIE (-6.1%)",
      "FISERV INC (-4.8%)",
      "ALPHABET INC-C (-4.7%)",
      "MONDELEZ INTER-A (-4.7%)",
      "PROCTER & GAMBLE (-4.6%)",
      "ASSA ABLOY AB-B (-4.6%)",
      "SEGRO PLC (-4.4%)",
      "APPLE INC (-4.1%)",
      "AMAZON.COM INC (-3.6%)",
      "PEPSICO INC (-2.6%)",
      "VESTAS WIND SYST (-1.3%)",
      "ANHEUSER-BUSCH I (-0.4%)",
      "ROCHE HLDG-GENUS (0.3%)",
      "VISA INC-CLASS A (1%)",
      "UNITEDHEALTH GRP (2.3%)",
      "DEUTSCHE TELEKOM (2.6%)",
      "ALLIANZ SE-REG (3%)",
      "ACCOR SA (3.2%)",
      "NOVO NORDISK-B (3.4%)",
      "ELI LILLY & CO (4.8%)",
      "ARCELORMITTAL (4.8%)",
      "RWE AG (5.8%)",
      "PALO ALTO NETWOR (6.3%)",
      "SPIRIT AEROSYS-A (8.2%)",
      "CATERPILLAR INC (8.5%)",
      "UNION PAC CORP (8.7%)",
      "LONDON STOCK EX (12.3%)",
      "QUANTA SERVICES (15.3%)",
      "ADP (17%)",
      "MTU AERO ENGINES (18.2%)",
      "FREEPORT-MCMORAN (21.6%)",
      "EQUINOR ASA (31.9%)",
      "ANGLO AMER PLC (33.2%)",
      "CHEVRON CORP (42.4%)"
    ),
    myColors = c(
      "#9C0824FF",
      "#A10A22FF",
      "#A50B21FF",
      "#AA0D1FFF",
      "#AF0E1DFF",
      "#B4101BFF",
      "#B81118FF",
      "#BD1316FF",
      "#C01416FF",
      "#C31417FF",
      "#C61517FF",
      "#C81518FF",
      "#CB1618FF",
      "#CE1619FF",
      "#D11719FF",
      "#D3241FFF",
      "#D52D24FF",
      "#D73629FF",
      "#D93D2FFF",
      "#DB4434FF",
      "#DD4B3AFF",
      "#DF513FFF",
      "#E35847FF",
      "#E8604EFF",
      "#EC6756FF",
      "#F06E5DFF",
      "#F47565FF",
      "#F87C6DFF",
      "#FC8375FF",
      "#F78E81FF",
      "#F2998DFF",
      "#ECA399FF",
      "#E5ADA5FF",
      "#DDB7B1FF",
      "#D4C1BDFF",
      "#CACACAFF",
      "#C5C9C2FF",
      "#BFC8B9FF",
      "#B9C6B1FF",
      "#B4C5A8FF",
      "#AEC4A0FF",
      "#A8C297FF",
      "#A2C18FFF",
      "#9ABD88FF",
      "#92BA82FF",
      "#8AB67BFF",
      "#82B275FF",
      "#7AAE6EFF",
      "#71AB67FF",
      "#69A761FF",
      "#62A35CFF",
      "#5AA058FF",
      "#529C53FF",
      "#4A994FFF",
      "#42954AFF",
      "#399246FF",
      "#2F8E41FF",
      "#2D8B3FFF",
      "#2A873EFF",
      "#28843CFF",
      "#25813AFF",
      "#237D38FF",
      "#207A37FF",
      "#1E7735FF",
      "#1B7433FF",
      "#197132FF",
      "#166E30FF",
      "#136B2FFF",
      "#10682DFF",
      "#0D652CFF",
      "#09622AFF"
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(
    9L,
    49L,
    2L,
    37L,
    17L,
    11L,
    55L,
    15L,
    27L,
    36L,
    12L,
    64L,
    56L,
    60L,
    14L,
    8L,
    53L,
    59L,
    51L,
    10L,
    38L,
    16L,
    62L,
    68L,
    33L,
    57L,
    5L,
    25L,
    32L,
    13L,
    71L,
    45L,
    50L,
    44L,
    4L,
    20L,
    29L,
    69L,
    54L,
    1L,
    22L,
    18L,
    41L,
    67L,
    52L,
    6L,
    21L,
    39L,
    19L,
    35L,
    61L,
    31L,
    3L,
    26L,
    7L,
    30L,
    34L,
    65L,
    70L,
    58L,
    46L,
    43L,
    42L,
    28L,
    47L,
    40L,
    48L,
    66L,
    24L,
    63L,
    23L
  )
))
```

Comment: Hi @Nuller, could you please share your (sample) data using `dput(data)`?

Comment: @Quinten - I have commented the dput data in this post. Didnt know the dput function! Neat! Thanks.

Comment: @Quinten and the requried packages are also edited in now.